# Need Image to Overflow Div in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer, html, overflow

I have a div class I named `.header` with a height of 30px.

Within the `.header div` I have an image *I want* to overflow out of it.

The image is 50px tall and it overflows in Chrome and Firefox.

Why does it not overflow in Internet Explorer? The `.header div` just expands to the 50px so it no longer overflows.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I edited your question to make it easier to read and to add some formatting.  I also fixed the tags, so it gets the right interest.

Comment: IE loves letting containers expand to their contents' size. Which verison of IE are you on? If you're working with IE6, go outside out smack yourself around with a rotten fish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want it to work in all browsers you could give the div a background image for example

```
<div style="background: url(your_image.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat;" >
</div>
```

or if you want the content to overflow out of the div try

```
<div style="overflow: visible;" >
</div>
```

Comment: I agree with above, and of course put it in an external for best use.

Answer (score 0):

For IE you need to set the div containing the image or the image itself to:

```
position:relative;
```

That should work fine and display the overflow of the image.